# Dynamic calls to allocateCapacity / deallocateCapacity from other components

Tags: frontend, redhawksdr

I'm developing a FRONTEND compliant Redhawk device on RHEL 5 with Redhawk 1.9.0.  After reading through the documentation, I'm still having a little bit of trouble understanding whether it's possible to dynamically allocate tuners at runtime from components that use the device.  My current understanding of the allocation property paradigm is that the Application Factory is the one that holds a direct reference to the Device and calls allocateCapacity on it directly at the time of instantiation of the dependent component.  This still leaves me with a few questions:

1. Is it possible for a component, during its lifetime after instantiation, to request further allocation of tuners dynamically?  If so, how?  Is there a way to get a reference to the FRONTEND device at runtime, or should this be accomplished through messaging?
2. When using the allocation property dependency strategy, how does the dependent component know at runtime what allocationId was used?  Is this queryable somehow?
3. I'm having trouble setting up an allocation property dependency using the Redhawk IDE.  The "Dependency Wizard" in the IDE doesn't seem to allow for specifying property references that have struct values -- am I going about this the wrong way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the newest version of REDHAWK, 1.10, there are tools in the IDE that assist in the allocation and deallocation of Frontend devices. This is possible by expanding the device in the the SCA Explorer view, and choosing to perform an allocation on that specific device. In 1.9 however the proposed solution is listed below.

There are ways of accomplishing dynamic allocations, and establishing device relationships outside of the Application Factory. The Application Factory performs the following operations when launching waveforms/components:

1. Calling load and execute on the executable / loadable device, and fulfilling any co-location requirements.
2. Allocating against device resources, and keeping track of the necessary relationships when an allocation succeeds.
3. Establishing connections between components.
4. Establishing connections between components and their associated devices, services, eventchannels, etc.
5. Initializing overloaded properties by calling configure() on the components.
6. Creating the waveform object responsible for tracking waveform lifecycle, and waveform specific attributes.

The Application factory parses the sad.xml files which is not very dynamic in nature. In 1.9 the dynamic entity controlling the device/component interactions must be an external resourse, such as a python script, or a component. In order to create your own tasking mechanism for Frontend Interface enabled devices you can create an asset that performs the following steps. These steps can be done in any language, but for simplicity, python snippets are shown using the redhawk python utility:

1. Launch your waveforms/components as normal, or reference something that's running.

   ```
   from ossie.utils import redhawk
   dom = redhawk.attach('REDHAWK_DEV') #OR your Domain Nameapplication = dom.createApplication('APPNAME')
   ```
2. Create the property for allocation.

   ```
   prop = Your_Property_used_for_Allocation
   ```
3. Cycle through all your devices in the domain and try allocating on them.

   ```
   myDevice = None
   for ii in dom.devMgrs:
       for jj in ii.devs:
           if (jj.allocateCapacity(prop)):
               myDevice = jj
               break
   if not myDevice:
       print 'Could Not Allocate... Exiting'
       exit()
   ```
4. Make a connection between the device that fulfilled allocation and waveform/component.

   ```
   outPort = myDevice.getPort('NAME OF USES PORT')
   inPort = application.getPort('NAME OF PROVIDES PORT')outPort.connectPort(inPort, 'connection name based off allocation id')
   ```
5. Keep track of these relationships so connections, etc, can be brought down when deallocating.